# Protecting IBM MobileFirst adapter procedures to be accessible only from another adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm using MobileFirst 6.3. I have an adapter, which procedures should be accessed only from another adapter of my application, but not from the client. What kind of security test can I use for that purpose? I couldn't find any so far. Or maybe there is another approach?

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, if you don't want your client logic to use an adapter - don't call the adapter in that client logic. Call the adapter only from another adapter...

There is no security to apply here.

Comment: I don't want client to have even possibility to call these procedures, they are dealing with secret data(some tokens from db).

Comment: By client I mean your application's logic. The code you write. Don't call the procedure in your code, it won't get called.

Comment: By client I mean javascript code that will work on the phones, and you can easily run any js code from console. So from that console you can write js code that will have access to this adapter procedures. I don't want that.

Comment: Why would anyone know your procedure names if you do not put the name in your code? Your looking for trouble where there is none.

Comment: It is not secure to rely on complexity of adapter name when we talk about secret data.

Comment: In my opinion your scenario is invalid. I personally am not aware of anything that there's to do here. I have nothing else to add.

Comment: Common practice -- assuming i understand this thread -- is to have an adapter with no public procedures (defined in xml).  Then have another adapter with public procedures that call the private adapter (WL.server.invokeProcedure), passing in any arguments.

Comment: [hit send to quick].  
Regardless, *ANY* logic in the adapters is run server side, and is hidden from public view, so your security concerns do not seem valid in this context.

Comment: @KarlBishop I've tried to call adapter procedures that are not defined in xml from another adapter using WL.server.invokeProcedure, but it didn't work